# Adding class to element with Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have this pen: https://codepen.io/nuzze/pen/gOYjKmx

As you see, I have 2 items with 3 properties (name, id, location).

So, when you click on the favorites button, a class named "favorites" its added to the 'li' tag and when you click again (unfavorite) the "favorites" class is removed. But now, I want to add statically the 'location' propertie as a class.
Let's see an example with 'Camp Nou' item:

```
{
    name: 'Camp Nou',
    id: 'campNou',
    location: '10'
}
```

The result I want is the next one:

```
<li class="10"></li>
```

And if is marked as favorites..

```
<li class="10 favorites"></li>
```

Hope you can help me, I have been with this problem for a long time.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically add a class with the `:class=""` attribute. Just pass an object to it, if you want to add a static class on condition. If you want to add a dynamic class (derived from a property), you can just pass it as a value to `:class=""`. If you have multiple classes, you want to set, you can use an array and combines these variants. Here is an example in which I assume that you have an object `location` and a method `isFavorite(locationId)`.

```
<li :class="[ location.id, { favorite: isFavorite(location.id) } ]"></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<li :class="[{'favorites': complejosVotes[complejo.id]}, complejo.location]">
```

... will do.

See it [working](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/BaBOjvQ).

Do note if you want to use class names starting with numbers or special characters you need to escape them (`.10` selector becomes `.\31 0`, as you replace `1` with `\31` - ending space required, and it doesn't have the usual meaning of spaces in CSS selectors - here it means *"end of escape sequence"*).

It gets as weird as this:

```css
.\30 {
  color: red;
}
.\31 {
  color: blue;
}
.\31  .\30 {
  color: orange;
}
.\31 .\30 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="0">.0</div>
<div class="1">
  .1
  <div class="0">.1 .0</div>
</div>
<div class="1 0">.1.0</div>
```

As you can see, `.\31 .\30` gets parsed into `.1.0`, not into `.1 .0`. You need two spaces for "normal" CSS space combinator.

Personal advice: don't use numeric classes. It's an unnecessary layer of complexity. You'd be better off with a mapper method, along these lines:

```
<li :class="[{'favorites': complejosVotes[complejo.id]}, locationClass(complejo.location)]">
```

```js
methods: {
  locationClass(location) {
    return location < 5
      ? 'sm-location'
      : location > 10
        ? 'lg-location'
        : 'md-location'
  }
}
```

... which will produce `sm-location` class if location value is under `5`, `lg-location` if above `10` or `md-location` otherwise. Obviously, change the mapper to whatever makes sense for your case.